# Finder & Quick Preview display broken JPEG thumbnail

Tags: finder, preview, quicklook, macos

In macOS 10.15.7 Catalina, some images are displayed with green stripes in the thumbnail in Finder and Quick Preview (press Spacebar). However, the image displays correctly when opening in various photo apps like Preview app, Photoshop.

To solve the problem, I have to re-save the JPEG with **max quality** in the Preview app. Save in the default quality (70% I guess?) won't have any effects at all.

**My question is:** How to identify these JPEGs (either programmatically / using some software)? When I use `jpeginfo` (installed via Homebrew) to check the JPEG, it shows it's OKAY.

```
jpeginfo --info --check ./error.jpg 
./error.jpg 3841 x 2881 24bit Exif  Normal Huffman 1068217  [OK]
```

---

**UPDATE** According to the Internet, the tool `jpeginfo` is outdated, and cannot diagnose JPEG errors well, as it only checks some key points in the metadata. Now trying other tools...

The problematic image:

[image: The original image]

In Finder:

[image: in Finder]

Quick Preview:

[image: Quick preview]

Comment: See if rebuilding the thumbnails fixes it - try https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150799/how-to-force-finder-to-update-file-thumbnails

Comment: Thanks, but this only appears in certain images, not all. Also, I tried the method in the quoted question, didn't help. Apparently, it's caused by the metadata of the JPEG.

Comment: Do you tried to render the files new? `sips --setProperty jpeg input.jpg --out output.jpg˚

Comment: Tried the command, no output file is generated. Tried the `--debug` and `--verify` flag, still the same. For the `--repair` flag, it generated: `Error: Cannot do --repair on file` and `Error 13: an unknown error occurred`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that exists in macOS 10.15, and is now fixed in macOS 12 Monterey.